# Mapping localization tables in Nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

Im building a localized application. All data needs to be available in different languages. As a storage model I try to use Nhibernate because of the better performance over Entity Framework. I store a root node in the database to get a unique Id for an entity and then I have a second table with the child nodes per language (the locale table).

My database table looks like:

```
Country
   Int Id;
Country_Locale
   Int Id;
   Int CountryId;
   String LangCode;
   String Name;

City
   Int Id;
   Int CountryId;
City_Locale
   Int Id;
   Int CityId;
   String LangCode;
   String Name;
```

My prefered Entities would look like

```
Country
  Int Id (from Coutry table)
  String LangCode (from locale table)
  String Name (from locale table)
  IList<City> Cities (Referenced to City entity)
City
  Int Id (From City table)
  String LangCode (from locale table)
  String Name (from locale table)
  Country Country (Referenced to Country entity)
  Int CountryId (From country table)
```

I realize that I cannot map the above, but it is a sort of the structure I would prefer. How could I do this mapping or are there other suggestions.

**
 Edited the database table layout to make it a little more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a similar approach to your first attempt with separate tables, and in the end I stuck with it and it worked out quite well. Here are my Fluent Mapping files (I'm using Fluent NHibernate) and some example code for retrieving the data back out of the database:

```
using FluentNHibernate.Mapping;

namespace Core.Mapping
{    
    public class CountryMap : ClassMap<Country>
    {
        public CountryMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id);

            Map(x => x.IsoCode)
                .Length(2)
                .Not.Nullable();

            HasMany(x => x.Translations)
                .Fetch.Join()
                .Not.LazyLoad()
                .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
        }
    }
}
```

The Country translations are actually stored as a separate class / table which I realize isn't exactly what you're looking for, but it works out quite well because in the end ***you have one table in which all of your translations are stored***. Here are the Fluent mapping classes:

```
using FluentNHibernate.Mapping;

namespace Core.Mapping
{
    public class CountryTranslationMap : ClassMap<CountryTranslation>
    {
        public CountryTranslationMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id);

            Version(x => x.LastModified);

            Map(x => x.Culture)
                .Length(2)
                .Not.Nullable();

            Map(x => x.Name)
                .Length(50)
                .Not.Nullable();

            References(x => x.Country);
        }
    }
```

}

Here are some examples from my Data Access layer for retrieving Countries by either the Culture or the ISO code (here I'm using the NHibernate QueryOver syntax):

```
    public IList<Country> GetAll(string culture)
    {
        var countryLanguageValue = new CountryTranslation();

        IList<Country> results = UnitOfWork.CurrentSession.QueryOver<Country>()
            .Fetch(x => x.Translations).Eager
            .JoinAlias(q => q.Translations, () => countryLanguageValue, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
            .Where(() => countryLanguageValue.Culture == culture)
            .OrderBy(x => x.DisplayOrder).Asc
            .List();

        return results;

    }

    public Country GetCountryByIsoCode(string isoCode)
    {
        var result = UnitOfWork.CurrentSession.QueryOver<Country>()
            .Where(x => x.IsoCode == isoCode)
            .List()
            .FirstOrDefault();

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was already looking at a similar approach. It indeed works quite well. I like the eager load stuff, indeed very handy/needed in this scenario (and I did not yet implemented that.)

Answer (score 0):

You can add computed properties of your own to your entities to retrieve things such as the CountryId from the City's child Country and have the CountryId property on the City object, because the mapper will replace that Id field with the actual Country entity.

```
public int CountryId { get { return this.Country.Id; } }
```

Unfortunately I think auto-mapping would be a pain if you keep _ prefixes on some (what seem to be unnecessary- to me), tables of your database but not others; if you can eliminate that your tables look very ripe for automapping as explained in this guide on their wiki:

https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Auto-mapping

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the tricky thing here is that you want to have your `CountryId` accessible from the `City` Entity. I don't see exactly why because you have already a reference to your country and simply doing `Country.Id` from your `City` you will have it.

```
var countryID = myCityEntity.Country.Id;
```

BTW if you need this for some particular reason you don't even need to map it, just think in a [Domain Drive Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design) way instead of plain POCOs and let the entity do this.

```
public int CountryId {
    get {
        return this.Country.Id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, though I not looking in this part of the mapping but in making one class based of 2 database tables to make the object more natural to work with. So I have now a table and a localizatoin table per entity. In the classes I prefer to have 1 class.